Is it reasonable to ignore const functions in Rust and treat them as a premature optimisation?
While I'm far from an expert at Rust, I'm becoming a proficient Rust user; I've written a substantial Rust library that is now being used in production. While I understand what const fns are, I haven't yet thought at all about how or where I should be using them in my app. But each Rust release I see people very excited about functions that can now be used in const contexts, and when people talk about Rust weaknesses the remaining parts of the standard library that aren't const fn are often mentioned.
While I'm sure const fn could at times be a big help, it also seems to me to be something that you could spend a lot of time worrying over for a limited benefit, ie a premature optimisation. Is that a fair take? Or are there times when const fns really are basically essential?

const fns can be part of type level modeling. They are useful in situations where you are dealing with things like generic arrays. Allowing you to move more things from runtime assertions to compile time proofs of correctness.

@user1937198 Yes setting the length of an array seems the most useful thing. Though a Vec is an option too, just a little less efficient.

In short
Although it looks like premature optimisation,  in reality the const fn is a requirement for some specific use cases.  So the thoughts should rather be driven by:  "would I need this function in some const context" rather than "will I win 10 ns at runtime".
More details
Yes, it looks like premature optimisation
Indeed, const fn could be seen as premature optimisation, if focusing on compile-time dimension of their official definition:

A const fn is a function that one is permitted to call from a const context. Declaring a function const has no effect on any existing uses, it only restricts the types that arguments and the return type may use, and restricts the function body to constant expressions.
When called from a const context, the function is interpreted by the compiler at compile time. The interpretation happens in the environment of the compilation target and not the host.

But the constraints are not so severe. The following dummy  const function for example does not look very constant, and I wonder if const fn could bring some compile time performance improvements beyond constant propagation which is anyway done:
const fn ftest (t: &mut i32, u: &i32) -> i32 {
    *t += 1 + *u;
    return 2 * *u + *t;
}

So optimisation might not be the prime reason. And reread the definition now, especially its very first sentence and purpose.
No, it isn't premature optimisation
const fn are required, if they need to be used in a const context, for example to calculate the size of an array or the initial value of a static.  The above function will fail miserably because of the mutable reference.
To be used in a const context,  const fn is therefore necessary but not sufficient:  input parameters are tested for constness as well.
Take the following function:
const fn fib (n:i32) -> usize{
    if n==0 {
        return 1; 
    }
    else if n==1 {
        return 1; 
    }
    else {
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
}

If I use it on a random number, it won't be constant. There will may be some tail recursion optimisation, but not much with constness.  But if I use it on const arguments, I could use it as an array size initialiser:
const y:i32 = 4; 
...
let array: [i32; fib(y)]; 

This works only if fib is a const fn.  If it wasn't const, the compilation would fail.  I would make it const only if there is a chance that I may need it in a const context.
Online demo
Usage rather than optimisation is the driver for the choice.

Why is this useful? Say you want an array of bytes that can hold a serialized struct. This allows you to calculate that size rather than hard-coding it, or needing to heap allocate the buffer.

@user1937198 You are probably right. I'm not arguing for using fixed sized arrays, I just took an example where const fn could be needed, to use a language feature and and the same time promote expressivity. And if Rust has fixed size arrays, there could be a reason justifying their use from time to time ;-)

@user1937198, I think what this answer is saying without explicitly saying it, is that intent matters. Why are you using const fns? If it is because you think it will execute fast enough to matter without profiling your application to find the true bottleneck, then yes, it is premature optimization. If you are writing a reusable library and you aren't sure of all the use cases in which it gets used, then no, it's not premature optimization; it's good library design.

@GregBurghardt Its probably not clear in text. That was a rhetorical question that I was answering. the assumption being you have decided (based on whatever appropriate decision making) you want a stack allocated array rather than a dynamic heap allocated buffer. Without this, you would be forced to hard code the calculated size. With this, you can calculate the appropriate size.

Its not an optimization of heap vs stack. Its when you go to stack (as an optimisation or otherwise), it allows for static correctness checking/modeling.

No, it’s not a premature optimization as it’s not an optimization at all, any more than types are an optimization.
Using const fn gives the compiler information about the context required to execute the function, then the compiler does any optimization it deems appropriate given the input. Even if a conforming implementation is required to precompute the results under certain circumstances, its intent is not optimization but clarity.
In fact, it’s the opposite of a premature optimization — in any situation where a const fn results in a compile time value, the same thing could be achieved by hard coding the results, which would generally be shorter.
Consider, this doubling function:
const fn double(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x * 2
}

const FIVE: i32 = 5;
const TEN: i32 = double(FIVE);

The definition of TEN could just as easily be const TEN: i32 = 10; it will compile to exactly the same code, the resulting binary won’t be any faster or smaller, won’t execute a different code path, they are 100% equivalent.  Except you put in more effort to give context to the first.
Now that may sound a lot like the result of premature optimization (and why it should be avoided), but the fact that you had purpose other than optimization is important. Even if the second definition was somehow faster or smaller, you’d still pick the first —- it makes the code more readable.
Don’t avoid making your code clearer for fear of being accused of premature optimization.


Is it reasonable to ignore const functions in Rust?

No. It is an important feature of the language. You are using Rust. You should think in terms of performance, the language was designed to provide maximum performance. Other features are nice, but at the end of the day, modern but less efficient languages (like Python, Java or C#) are so much easier to use. At the end of the day safety but only together with performance is what makes Rust so appealing.

Is const fn a premature optimization?

No. It is a feature of the language, and as such how can it be a premature optimization? It is up to you how you utilize it.
Premature optimization is often an overused term. If your goal is to write an efficient, optimized software, then how is that premature? Especially when it doesn't really cost you anything to add const keyword. And the only price you might pay is compilation time and binary size. Although the latter is far less important than the former, unless you write code for some embedded system.

Is const fn an optimization?

Yes. When you develop performant software it is important to move whatever you can to compile time. Because for users it is runtime that matters, not compile time. And that's what const fn let you do. Well, maybe not always, sometimes we are interested in small binaries (which often is opposite to fast runtime). And so as with any tool you need to figure out yourself whether you need it or not.
There are certain other advantages. For example you can panic in const functions, which allows making custom compile time validations.

"When you develop performant software it is important to move whatever you can to compile time" The 80/20 rule applies here - in most cases, it is not important, because it makes no measurable difference to performance. You would be better spending your time looking at other areas of the code.

@PhilipKendall yeah, and that's why in 2024 we have so much software that runs slower than in 90's (relative to hardware capabilities and sometimes even absolutely) and eats hundreds or thousands of Mb of memory for no apparent reason. The consequence of not caring for performance. Those "non measurable things" simply stack. I apply the opposite rule.

Also, I've never said you should ignore other areas of the code. Or that they are less important. We are not talking about other areas here. And as I said: adding const hardly costs anything, especially doesn't cost any development time, come on.

Adding const if I happen to spot a function which can be const while developing doesn't cost time, I agree. Commenting on a PR in a non-performance critical section saying "this function can be const. When you develop in Rust, it is important to move whatever you can to compile time." does take up a significant amount of the whole team's time.

@PhilipKendall does it? I don't think so. Also, people spend 99% of PR time on bikeshedding, like variable naming. That would be a nice change to actually talk about important stuff.

Adding constness is not a premature optimisation at all. You tell the compiler that something should be unchangeable. If changing it would be a bug, then constness prevents the bug. So you have better code, easier to maintain, easier to check for correctness, easier to argue about. These are qualities that your code should have as early as possible, they are never premature.

This would be true if const functions would actually prevent some changes.  This is the case for example in C++ member functions where making them const allows them  to be called on const objects and at the same time prevent accidental change of the object state (oh, these = instead of ==...).  In rust however,  const fn do not prevent changes.  The purpose is slightly different.

const fns in rust have nothing to do with C++ const. They map to the C++ concept of constexpr functions.
